# Location of gem configuration file gemrc in ubuntu? Its not at home(~/.gemrc) or at /etc/gemrc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed ruby 1.9.3p194 using rvm on ubuntu 12.04. **Its not at home(~/.gemrc) or at /etc/gemrc**
Does rvm places gem configuration file gemrc somewhere else?

Is there any way i could find out where this files kept...by giving some option to $ gem command. Actually i want to disable by default rdoc and ri installation when any new gem is installed. For that i want to modify gemrc file which as :

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri 
update:  --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can locate any file on a Linux/Ubuntu system using locate, e.g.:

```
locate gemrc
```

But it's possible you don't have one yet. You can just create it yourself in your homedir (or even /etc/gemrc if you want to apply it to all users.) You're right that rvm does not install one by default (at least it didn't on my system.) So just do:

```
vi ~/.gemrc
```

And insert those lines you wrote in your post, it should work.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it works . I did chat with Michael Papis on irc #rvm channer and he too confirmed that if we do not user binary rubies (e.g. installing ruby with rvm) then gemrc file will not be there under ~/.gemrc or /etc/gemrc.  So created one as ~/.gemrc and put it there <pre> gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri </pre> and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Always good to get some confirmation from the horse's mouth ^^